# template for loop with non-const arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

In cpp you can use two cheat codes to effectively have a for-loop over template arguments, which the compiler will accept. This is shown below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<size_t k> void increment(size_t* v, size_t& i){ v[k]=i*i++; }

int main(){
    const size_t N = 10;
    size_t v[N], i=0;

    // for(size_t k=0;k<N;++k){ increment<k>(v,i); } // this would not work
    
    // so we write the following instead
    [v,i]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<k...>){ // this line is the first cheat code
        (increment<k>(v,i), ...); // loop body
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); // this line is the second cheat code
    
    for(size_t k=0;k<N;++k){ std::cout << v[k] << " , "; }
}
```

Question: The code won't compile because in the line *loop body*, the compiler requires v,i to be const. But as the example points out, I do not want them const. Thus, I am asking for that cheat code, which makes it work. If multiple cheat codes exist, I want the shortest.

Comment: Why exactly do you call every c++ feature "cheat code"? You probably want a mutable lambda.

Comment: whats the actual problem you are trying to solve? I am certain that there are ways do to it that do not require cheats and tricks

Comment: Caution: `i*i++` introduces undefined behavior. `v[k]=i*i;++i;` will do what it looks like you're after in that line.

Comment: Much simpler and more efficient to use a non-templated function: https://godbolt.org/z/M7r97xEnP there's no point using templates here as the code does the same thing regardless of the value of `k` which just makes the compiler generate redundant copies of your function

Comment: You need to capture `v` and `i` by reference and you need to rename `Is` to `k`, it looks like a copy/paste error. If you need to pass by copy and modify the captured object, make the lambda `mutable`.

Comment: There are no cheat codes in C++. C++ isn't a computer game. You may be looking for the terms "feature", "solution" or "pattern".

Answer (score 6):

The `mutable` keyword can be used to allow a lambda expression to modify objects iT captures by value.

You also need to capture `v` by reference or `increment` will be called on a copy of `v` and have no visible effect.

Live example : https://godbolt.org/z/4xbPe4MdP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<size_t k> void increment(size_t* v, size_t& i){ v[k]=i*i++; }

int main(){
    constexpr std::size_t N = 10;
    std::size_t v[N];

    [&v,i = std::size_t{}]<std::size_t... k>(std::index_sequence<k...>) mutable
    {
        (increment<k>(v,i), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    
    for(std::size_t k=0;k<N;++k){ std::cout << v[k] << " , "; }
}
```